# Pros and cons of interest bearing elastic supply (rebase) tokens

Tags: tokens, aave, compound-protocol

Single asset vaults usually choose from 2 types of tokens that represent user shares.

- Tokens pegged 1:1 to underlying assets employing the **rebase architecture**. When underlying asset volume grows then the supply of such tokens is increased to hold 1:1 peg. *Examples: AAVE's aTokens, Overnight's USD+;*
- **Constant supply tokens** representing user's share of a vault. When underlying asset volume grows then the token supply remains the same but the peg of the token to the underlying assets naturally increases. *Examples: Compound's cToken.*

What are **the pros and the cons** of the elastic supply tokens?

From the usability standpoint:

- When a rebase token is provided to liquidity pools do additional difficulties emerge for the pool to preserve the interest for the user?
- When an exact amount of a rebase token is sent to a recipient does the one get this precise amount? Actually behind the scene what is transferred is the principal – does rounding errors appear?
- Also an additional interest gets accrued after the transfer which could bring difficulties to the accounting. Is there any bad experience around accounting on a rebase token?

From the engineering standpoint:

- The rebase architecture brings additional complexity. What are gas spendings implications?
- Are there any limitations on such architecture? What functionality is impossible to be implemented for a rebase token?